# Como implementar autentificación por token para una api en DRF?

Tags: python, django, api, djangorestframework, tokens

Estoy desarrollando un proyecto en Django Rest Framework, hay cree 2 apis, una de ellas es para crear usuario.

En settings.py puse esta variable para bloquear las apis y que funcionen por token

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    )
}
```

Pero una de esas apis que se bloquean es la de usuarios, como puedo hacer que se bloquen las demás a excepción de usuarios para que se pueda generar el token.

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo resolví, ingrese estas lineas en el archivo de la api:

```
authentication_classes = ()
permission_classes = ()
```

Con eso la autentificacion no aplica a la api de usuarios